# how to return response after finishing the for loop in node.js express?

Tags: node.js, express

In my `node.js express` `server` i have the `api` function in which i am doing `async` operations `for-of` loop.

`controller.js`

```
const importRecords = async(req,res) => {
    for (const bid of distinctArr) {
       // doing 3 async operations for each loop iteration with `await`
       let transaction = await db.sequelize.transaction();
       let bidCreate = await createBid(bid.bid, transaction)
       if(bidCreate){
          let usersCreate = await createUsers(bid.users, transaction);
          let ordersCreate = await ordersCreate(bid.orders, transaction)
          await transaction.commit();
       }
    }
    return{
      status: true,
      message: "Records imported successfully",
      response: null,
    }
}
```

`handler.js`

```
exports.ImportBookings = async(req, res) => {
 try {
    const result = await importNewBookings(req);
    res.json(result);
 } catch (error) {
    res.status(error.code || 500).send({
        code: error.code,
        message: error.message,
        response: null
    })
 }
}
```

`routes.js`

```
router.post('/import-bookings', ImportBookings)
```

You can see that i am returning the response after loop finishes but the problem is that all the `operations/db entries` are doing well but `response` is not returning to the `api`. How can i do that?

**Note: I just included the necessary code to just show problem statement**

Comment: Try Promise.all befoer async.

Comment: I am using `mysql` with `node.js` along with `sequelize`. So in the `for` loop i am doing 3 db entries for each array iteration and using `transaction`. So in the end of each array's iteration i am `comitting` that `transaction`. So what should i pushes into the `promises` array?

Comment: @RichardRublev please see my updated question

Comment: If you also include how the function `importRecords` is used by the express router/app, we might be able to see what the problem is.

Comment: @lenkan please see my updates question. I added it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So finally i resolved my problem. I simply just wrap-up my whole working inside of `Promise` and then i put my returning `object` to `promise's` `resolve` so that it resolves the promise value when loop finishes. Here is my updated code of function which is now working fine.

`controller.js`

```
const importRecords = async(req,res) => {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     for (const bid of distinctArr) {
      // doing 3 async operations for each loop iteration with `await`
      let transaction = await db.sequelize.transaction();
      let bidCreate = await createBid(bid.bid, transaction)
       if(bidCreate){
          let usersCreate = await createUsers(bid.users, transaction);
          let ordersCreate = await ordersCreate(bid.orders, transaction)
          await transaction.commit();
       }
     }
     resolve({
      status: true,
      message: "Records imported successfully",
      response: null,
     })
   })
}
```

Comment: worked also without using sequlize libraries...

Answer (score 0):

You may favour the use of a lock in asynchronous JS. I guess your `distinctArr` is generator coz it's used with `of` keyword, change the `distinctArr.length` to something equivalent (for example: `Array.from(distinctArr).length`, `[...distinctArr].length`).

```
function newLock(){
    var unlock,lock=new Promise((res,rej)=>{ unlock=res; });
    return [lock,unlock];
}

const importRecords = async(req,res) => {
    // *** CREATE LOCK ***
    var [lock,unlock] = newLock();
    var doneCount     = 0;

    for (const bid of distinctArr) {
        // doing 3 async operations for each loop iteration with `await`
        let transaction = await db.sequelize.transaction();
        let bidCreate = await createBid(bid.bid, transaction)

        if (bidCreate){
            let usersCreate = await createUsers(bid.users, transaction);
            let ordersCreate = await ordersCreate(bid.orders, transaction)
            await transaction.commit();
        }

        // *** COUNT TRANSACTIONS DONE ***
        doneCount++;

        if (doneCount>=distinctArr.length)
            unlock();
    }

    // *** AWAIT THE LOOP TO BE DONE ***
    await lock;

    res.json({
        status: true,
        message: "Records imported successfully",
        response: null,
    });
}
```